# Selenium sendkey enviando texto desposicionado no textbox - C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Ao utilizar a função sendkeys no selenium, o valor enviado ao textbox sai desposicionado.

Isto acontece tanto para o Chrome quanto para o Firefox.

Ex.: estou enviando o valor 123456789 para o campo textbox e está chegando 234567891.

`var campo = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtNumero"));
campo.Clear();
campo.SendKeys("123456789");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme sugestão do Paulo, adicionei um click antes de enviar os dados. Para algumas situações, isto resolveu e para outras a alternativa foi utilizar o envio dos dados via javascript:

```
var valor_enviado = "123456789"
var campo = driver.FindElement(By.Id("nome_do_campo"))
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value='" + valor_enviado + "';", campo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar antes do SendKeys o .Click();

campo.Click();

campo.Clear();

campo.SendKeys("123456789");

Pode ser que o campo ainda não está selecionado e por isso deve perder o primeiro caractere.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Paulo, resolveu parcialmente. Para alguns sites, esta solução funcionou, porém para outros, não.